# Accessing TextBox ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a method that creates **Textboxes** each time the button is **clicked**.  However I am trying to access the `Textbox` **ID** in another method.  Something seems to be out of scope, here is the code:

```
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    TextBox box = new TextBox();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["count"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"]) + 1;
        Label1.Text = ViewState["count"].ToString();
        int test = int.Parse(string.Format("{0}", ViewState["count"]));

            for (int j = 0; j < test; j++)
            {

                TableRow r = new TableRow();

                box.ID = "Textbox" + j;

                TableCell c = new TableCell();
                c.Controls.Add(box);
                r.Cells.Add(c);
                table1.Rows.Add(r);
                Response.Write(box.ID);

            }

            if (test == 4)
            {
                Button1.Visible = false;
            }

    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Write(box.ID);
    }
```

I would like to `Button2_Click` to print out the `box.ID` to make sure it's able to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To always create as many text boxes as the number of times user clicked `Button1`, in your `Page_Load` you have to run code:

```
int test = 0;
if (ViewState["count"] != null)
   test = (int)ViewState["count"];

for (int j = 0; j < test; j++)
{
    TextBox box = new TextBox();
    box.ID = "Textbox" + j;
    textBoxes.Add(box.ID, box);
    TableRow r = new TableRow();
    TableCell c = new TableCell();
    c.Controls.Add(box);
    r.Cells.Add(c);
    table1.Rows.Add(r);
}
```

where `textBoxes` is a `Page` class member:

```
Dictionary<string, TextBox> textBoxes = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>();
```

Then, in `Button2_Click`:

```
string ids = "";
foreach(string id in textBoxes.Keys)
{
    ids = ids + id + ",";
}
Response.Write(ids);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `Button1_Click` and `Button2_Click` events would be on two separate postbacks.  `Box` would not have any values assigned to it beyond whatever gets set in the default constructor in this scenario.

**Edit:**  Because you're losing the state of all your code-behind objects and values on postbacks.

Comment: Hi Cortright, Thanks that makes more sense.  How would the code look like if I were to access the textboxes?

Comment: You need to keep information about your textbox in a serializable object and store/retrieve that from the "Control State".

Comment: don't forget that in poster's code there is a single instance of `TextBox` that gets added to multiple `Controls` collections

Comment: @vadim I don't really recommend this as an approach, but you could do something like: `for (int i = 0;FindControl("Textbox" + string.Parse(i)) != null;i++) Response.Write(("Textbox" + string.Parse(i));`

Answer (score 2):

The key is you need to reload the dynmaically created controls on post back.

Otherwise, they will become null, and you cannot access the values.

***Note:*** you do not need to use `Response.Write`.

Here is the example.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="table1"></asp:Table>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" 
   Text="Create TextBoxes" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button2" OnClick="Button2_Click" 
  Text="Submit" />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        // Reload those control back. It can be in either init or load event.
        int total = Count;
        Label1.Text = total.ToString();

        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
            CreateTextBoxes(i);

        Count = total;
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Count = Count++;
    CreateTextBoxes(Count);

    if (Count == 4)
    {
        Button1.Visible = false;
    }
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var results = new List<string>();
    foreach (TableRow row in table1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            var textBox = cell.Controls[0] as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                results.Add(textBox.Text);
            }
        }
    }
    Label1.Text += string.Join(",", results);
}

private int Count
{
    get { return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"] ?? "0"); }
    set { ViewState["count"] = value; }
}

private void CreateTextBox(int j)
{
    var box = new TextBox();
    box.ID = "Textbox" + j;
    box.Text = "Textbox" + j;

    var c = new TableCell();
    c.Controls.Add(box);

    var r = new TableRow();
    r.Cells.Add(c);

    table1.Rows.Add(r);
}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: When I use this code and press 'Create Boxes' It only creates the first one Textbox0

Comment: Yes, you need to click `Create TextBoxes` again in order to create another textbox. I thought it is what you are asking.

Comment: That is.. Every time I click on Create TextBoxes it still stays at Textbox0

Comment: and also thank you for taking the time and helping me out.  I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

With the way **asp.net** works, you're recreating `box` on each postback (both when you click `Button1` and when you click `Button2`). So When you click `Button2`, even though you've run the code behind for `Button1`, you're getting a brand new `box.`

In `Button2`, you need to do something to access the `textbox` from the page itself where you added it. I'm not positive how to work with what you're doing but something like

```
var mytextBox = table1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Controls[z] as TextBox; // PSEUDOCODE
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I would use the code you provided.  The concept makes sense to me, just having trouble actually coding it.  Thanks for the help at least I understand what's going on!  Could you provide more detail on the code above?

Comment: That was just meant to be pseudocode. You're adding the textbox into the tree of controls (by adding it to the table's cell, which is added to the row's cell collection, and the row is added to the table, and I assume the table is on the page somewhere). So you could access it by indexing into all those collections, which is what I showed. There are probably other ways, but it depends on your setup.