# How I can select different text box when I am trying to fill the textbox using button control

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

I am trying to fill two text box in a form using button controls but it seems to work for 1 only. when I run the program, I can't select between two text box. what condition should I use?

```
private void Button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (???????????????????)
    {
        metroTextBoxQuantity.Text = metroTextBoxQuantity.Text + "0";
    }
    else
    {
        metroTextBoxItemcode.Text = metroTextBoxItemcode.Text + "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Which technology is this? WinForms? WebForms? WPF? UWP? MVC?

Comment: visual studio. windows form application

Comment: What condition allows you to successfully make the choice?

Comment: i can't find the solution, is there any method to select between 2 text box?

Comment: I believe you can find similar QnA such https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601725/accessing-textbox-id  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659916/c-sharp-change-textbox-name-in-code

Comment: No, in the first link they created the text box, but in my case i want to to select the text box.

Comment: You could use a variable which should set when the text box gets focus, then on button click use that variable to set the value, means you don't have to use the condition, just use the variable `currentTextBox.Text = `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to create a `Control` variable that stores a reference to the last clicked textbox. This would be handled by the `Click` event for both textboxes. Then, in your number button clicks, just append the number to the selected textbox variable. Something like this:

```
Control SelectedTextbox { get; set; } = null;

//Use this event handler for both the Quantity and Itemcode textbox
public TextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectedTextbox = (Control)sender;
}

private void Button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(SelectedTextbox == null)
        throw new Exception("SelectedTextbox has not been set");
    SelectedTextbox.Text += "0";
}
```

Note, if `MetroTextBox` doesn't inherit from `Control`, you'll need to change `SelectedTextbox` to a different type. It most likely does though.

You also may want to consider using a single event handler for all the button clicks instead of one for each. You can either parse what number button was clicked using the `sender`'s name, or you can store the number of the button in the button's `Tag` and read it from there. But that's best left for another question.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you so much for your help.  :)